# Why a particular URL web address exists but its parent folder does not exist

Tags: web, url

For example, when I run the following command in linux:

```
curl -I https://assets.thalia.media/images-adb/68/a5/68a5b9c3-2c0a-482b-9965-98d2167b14dd.pdf
```

The server returns HTTP/2 200, meaning the file exists. But if I visit any of this file's parent folder, for example:

```
curl -I https://assets.thalia.media/images-adb/68/a5/
```

The server returns HTTP/2 404, meaning the folder is not found. It even does not show 403 (access forbidden). My question is why a file can exist but its parent folder does not exist?

Answer (score 0):

When we create a website, we can decide which path in the url returns what.
It is not the same as the directories in your computer, that you can see and "travel" between them.

When create a website, you can "skip" paths and decided that they are "not implemented"